# Matplotlib Plotting: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xaxis'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

[Example Plot that needs to format date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5UH8.png)

I am trying to plot stock prices against time (see above). The code below does plot the "OPEN" prices but as I try to format the X-axis dates from ordinal to ISO dates, it throws `AttributeError`.

The same code worked while plotting the OHLC graph, but somehow this doesn't work now.

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xaxis'**

```
    df_copy = read_stock('EBAY')

    fig = plt.figure(figsize= (12,10), dpi = 80)
    ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
    ax1 = plt.plot(df_copy['Date'], df_copy['Open'], label = 'Open values' )
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: Try `df_copy.set_index('Date').Open.plot(label='Open values')`

Comment: That works! Thanks. However, my query remains. Why does it throw the error, specifying its a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

`ax1 = plt.plot(df_copy['Date'], df_copy['Open'], label='Open values')`

Refines your Axes object to be the list of artists returned by the `plot` command.

Instead of relying on the state machine to put artists on the Axes, you should use your objects directly:

```
df_copy = read_stock('EBAY')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10), dpi=80)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
lines = ax1.plot(df_copy['Date'], df_copy['Open'], label='Open values')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from you writing

```
ax1 = plt.plot(df_copy['Date'], df_copy['Open'], label = 'Open values' )
```

Since you are changing the type of ax1 from being the handle returned by `plt.subplot()`. After said line, it is a list of lines that were added to the plot, which explains your error message. See the documentary on the plot command:

> Return value is a list of lines that were added.
>   [matplotlib.org](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)