# Matplotlib Plotting: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'axhline'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting 3 charts in one figure.

The first chart came out fine and I could use the methods associated with a matplotlib chart.

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout = True, figsize = [10,10])
gs = fig.add_gridspec(4,2)
fig_ax_curve = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2,:])
```

However, as I proceeded with the second chart:

```
fig_ax_2_10 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2,:])
fig_ax_2_10 = fig_ax_2_10.plot(yield_history_2_10_30["2Y-10Y Spread"], label = "2Y - 10Y Spread", color = "red")
fig_ax_2_10.axhline(color = "black")
```

I was unable to execute any of the associated methods and got back:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'axhline'
```

I am aware of an existing question that was similar: [Matplotlib Plotting: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'xaxis'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376000/matplotlib-plotting-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-xaxis)

If I'm not mistaken, my code has already followed what is suggested in that answer to avoid the error, specifically using ax.(methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the line :

```
fig_ax_2_10 = fig_ax_2_10.plot(yield_history_2_10_30["2Y-10Y Spread"], label = "2Y - 10Y Spread", color = "red")
```

You are assigning the result of the plot function (a list of Line2D) to fig_ax_2_10. This is why you can not call axhline on that object.

Just replace :

```
fig_ax_2_10 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2,:])
fig_ax_2_10.plot(yield_history_2_10_30["2Y-10Y Spread"], label = "2Y - 10Y Spread", color = "red")
fig_ax_2_10.axhline(color = "black")
```